# Convert QDialog Plugin to QDockWidget

Tags: qgis-plugins, pyqt5

I have a QGIS 3 plugin that is in QDialog. Everything is functional but i want to change it to QDockWidget and dock it within QGIS. How can i convert it to QDockWidget?

I am using QGIS 3 with Pyqt5.

I have tried changing the default behvior from QDialog to QDockWidget, but that mess up with the styles.